# An example where Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm is faster than Boyer-Moore?

Tags: algorithms, substrings, matching

This [page](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/string-searching/index.html) about Knuth-Moriss-Pratt Algorithm compared to Boyer-Moore describes a possible case where the Boyer-Moore algorithm suffers from small skip distance while KMP could perform better.
I'm looking for a good example (text,pattern) that can clearly demonstrate this case.

Comment: SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656160/what-are-the-main-differences-between-the-knuth-morris-pratt-and-boyer-moore-sea

Answer (score 4):

Well these patterns will make KMP work faster:

T=aaaaaaaaaa P=aaaa
KMP will try 10 compare steps were Boyer-Moore will take 28

Another example:

T=aaaaaaaaaa P=abab KMP will try 8 compare steps where BM will try 12.

Comment: In the first example, both algorithms will find a match immediately, at the first shift - how would they make more than 4 comparisons?

Comment: That first example does not take 10 comparisons for KMP, it takes 28 for both algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper that did a good experiment over these string matching algorithms for different patterns:
"[Comparison of string matching algorithms: an aid to information content security](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1260090)"

Also there is a study of these string matching algorithms for Japanese language:
[Comparison and Improvement of String Matching Algorithms For Japanese Texts](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0586-02.pdf)

I hope these are useful to get a sense about algorithms efficiency!